# how to count sum of values from json object with php

Tags: php, json, count, sum

I have a couple of json files in a directory `data`.
Each json file looks like below:

```
{
    "id": "id_2021-04-01_1300",
    "starttime": "13:00",
    "endtime": "18:00",
    "hours": 5
}
```

To count the sum of all `hours` together from all json files, i have this code in php:

```
$files = glob('data/*.json'); // all json-files in array
foreach($files as $file) {
    $hours_arrays[] = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);
}
$total_hours = 0;
foreach($hours_arrays as $key => $val) {
    $total_hours += $val['hours'];
}
```

According to this code, `$total_hours` should contain the sum of all the hours from all json files. But i got back `0`. What i am doing wrong?

Comment: `var_dump($files)` gives back what? Do you have error reporting enabled?

Comment: that gives me back an array of all the json files

Comment: whats `print_r($hours_arrays);` show?

Comment: hmm, strange, it gives back: `array(0) { }`

Comment: Maybe `file_get_contents` is failing in that case? Code logic is correct https://3v4l.org/GDcmB so it is probably permissions or location.

Comment: If file_get_contents is failing than there will be some items with false in array. I think $files is empty

Comment: try to add a trim - `$hours_arrays[] = json_decode(trim(file_get_contents($file), true));`

Comment: Found the issue: above path is correct: `$files = glob('data/*.json'); `  but in my code i had `$files = glob('data*.json'); `(missing / )

Answer (score 0):

I just ran your code and it works fine. https://prnt.sc/1xzcibj. Debug that your files have correct path and you are recieving the content. Also check the parsed content of files in variable `$hours_arrays`. It should look like variable on my screenshot

Comment: if it works then there is a close vote for typos/unreproducible

Comment: I can not say that it works for this man. He should check the correctness of path to json files and check the content of files.